# Jekyll encoding name of category special characters

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, jekyll

My Jekyll installation used to work. Since an update, I face an issue with URL containing tag names which have some special characters.

I now get an error message when trying to reach a URL with special characters in it like `http://127.0.0.1:4000/tag/Actualit%C3%A9%20europ%C3%A9enne/`, where `Actualité européenne` is the name of a category.

The error message is `incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT`. All the files in `_posts` directory are utf-8.

Here is the stack trace :

> [2017-01-30 17:39:09] ERROR Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible
>   character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT
>     /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpservlet/filehandler.rb:313:in
>   'set_filename'
>     /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpservlet/filehandler.rb:282:in
>   'exec_handler'
>     /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpservlet/filehandler.rb:217:in
>   'do_GET'
>     /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve/servlet.rb:30:in
>   'do_GET'  /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpservlet/abstract.rb:106:in
>   'service'
>     /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpservlet/filehandler.rb:213:in
>   'service'     /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in 'service'
>     /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in 'run'
>     /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in 'block in start_thread'
>
> [2017-01-30 17:41:59] ERROR Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible
>   character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT
>     /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpservlet/filehandler.rb:313:in
>   'set_filename'
>     /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpservlet/filehandler.rb:282:in
>   'exec_handler'
>     /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpservlet/filehandler.rb:217:in
>   'do_GET'
>     /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve/servlet.rb:30:in
>   'do_GET'  /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpservlet/abstract.rb:106:in
>   'service'
>     /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpservlet/filehandler.rb:213:in
>   'service'     /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in 'service'
>     /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in 'run'
>     /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in 'block in start_thread'

I've renamed all the files in `_posts` to remove special characters in the **filenames**, but still does not work. I don't want to rename the tags.

Comment: Which ruby version are you suing?

Comment: My ruby version is ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13) [i386-linux-gnu]. My jekyll version is 3.4.0.

Comment: Okay, Thanks. Can post the code of _post file?

Comment: Well, _posts is a directory containing markdown files. Here is an example of such a file containing tags with special characters : http://pastebin.com/KdkudTiN

Comment: From what version did you update?

Comment: Also, what does `Encoding.find('filesystem')` return?

Comment: @Jordan I'm now home (7pm here). I've tried on my personal PC and it works well with Jekyll 3.3.0 and ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]. I could do the other test tomorrow.

Comment: @Jordan I think I've updated from jekyll 3.2.1 but cannot be sure, as this is done automatically and I don't test every incremental update. Your cmd returns "UTF-8".

Answer (score 1):

all the pages are encoded to 'utf-8' by default. but you can override this in `config.yml`:

```
encoding: ENCODING
```

but it seems that jekyll doesn't works well (until now: jan-2017) with unicode no english characters, see this similar issue [Slugify a string doesn't seem to work on Unicode/Swedish letters #4623](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4623). the space also my cause a little problem if you don't put the category inside `' '`

a fix whould be to slugify your "Catégories" explicitly before integrating them in the `url`, using a [generator](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#generators), with:

```
slug = category.strip.downcase.gsub(' ', '-').gsub(/[^\w-]/, '') # categories slugiffier  
// use this slug as the category id
```

the slugifier above just down case, replace space with -, and remove all non ascii letter, so you'll need to add other substitutions `gsub` before the last one `.gsub(/[^\w-]/, '')` to replace:

```
é è ê -> e
à â   -> a
...
```

### Update

while reading the old jekyll issues in GitHub list to implement a "fix" for that one, I found this [detailed solution](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-help/issues/129#issuecomment-61255284) posted by @david-jacquel on 2014 :

> This needs to change the way Jekyll generates urls for posts. This can
>   be done with a plugin.
>
> ```
> # _plugins/post.rb
> module Jekyll
>
>   class Post
>
>     # override post method in order to return categories names as slug
>     # instead of strings
>     #
>     # An url for a post with category "category with space" will be in
>     # slugified form : /category-with-space
>     # instead of url encoded form : /category%20with%20space
>     #
>     # @see utils.slugify
>     def url_placeholders
>       {
>           :year        => date.strftime("%Y"),
>           :month       => date.strftime("%m"),
>           :day         => date.strftime("%d"),
>           :title       => slug,
>           :i_day       => date.strftime("%-d"),
>           :i_month     => date.strftime("%-m"),
>           :categories  => (categories || []).map { |c| Utils.slugify(c) }.join('/'),
>           :short_month => date.strftime("%b"),
>           :short_year  => date.strftime("%y"),
>           :y_day       => date.strftime("%j"),
>           :output_ext  => output_ext
>       }
>     end
>
>   end
>
> end
> ```
>
> -- David Jacquel on [Jekyll/jekyll-help/issues/129#](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-help/issues/129#issuecomment-61255284)

that will resolve the space issue, and give a starter point to solve the encoding name

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad you could fully understand my problem. Your solution great, but complicated to me. As I could make it work on one of my computers (see comments above), I prefer to wait for an official fix rather than make my own stuff which will break everything on next update.

Comment: to make it work just put davide code in a file `post.rb` inside `_plugins` and build locally with `bundle exec jekyll b`.. but, as you said, a built-in support in slugify for characters with accent would be great