# Local jekyll cannot load unicode urls

Tags: url, unicode, http-status-code-404, jekyll, github-pages

My Local Jekyll's version is 4.0.0. and OS is Windows 10

I wanna access to '[http://localhost:4000/문제풀이/문제풀이/](http://localhost:4000/%EB%AC%B8%EC%A0%9C%ED%92%80%EC%9D%B4/%EB%AC%B8%EC%A0%9C%ED%92%80%EC%9D%B4/)', but I can't. only [shows 404page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wA5vC.png)
On the other hand, github pages's blog url '[https://neomindstd.github.io/문제풀이/문제풀이/](https://neomindstd.github.io/%EB%AC%B8%EC%A0%9C%ED%92%80%EC%9D%B4/%EB%AC%B8%EC%A0%9C%ED%92%80%EC%9D%B4/)'  is [accessible.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpD9e.png)

Below is Yaml Front Matter of '2020-02-11-문제풀이.md'

```
---
title:  "문제풀이 테스트"
excerpt: "테스트다"

categories:
  - 문제풀이
tags:
  - Blog
date: 2020-02-09 KST 04:34 +0900

toc: true
toc_sticky: true
toc_label: "목차"

published: true
---
```

part of _config.yml

```
# Outputting
permalink: /:categories/:title/
paginate: 5 # amount of posts to show
paginate_path: /page:num/
timezone: Asia/Seoul # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones
```

so, created: [.site/문제풀이/문제풀이/index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fPf1.png)

I've tried [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41941320/jekyll-encoding-name-of-category-special-characters).
add the _plugins/post.rb.

```rb
# https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-help/issues/129#issuecomment-61255284
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41941320/jekyll-encoding-name-of-category-special-characters
# _plugins/post.rb
module Jekyll

    class Post

      # override post method in order to return categories names as slug
      # instead of strings
      #
      # An url for a post with category "category with space" will be in
      # slugified form : /category-with-space
      # instead of url encoded form : /category%20with%20space
      #
      # @see utils.slugify
      def url_placeholders
        {
            :year        => date.strftime("%Y"),
            :month       => date.strftime("%m"),
            :day         => date.strftime("%d"),
            :title       => slug,
            :i_day       => date.strftime("%-d"),
            :i_month     => date.strftime("%-m"),
            :categories  => (categories || []).map { |c| Utils.slugify(c) }.join('/'),
            :short_month => date.strftime("%b"),
            :short_year  => date.strftime("%y"),
            :y_day       => date.strftime("%j"),
            :output_ext  => output_ext
        }
      end

    end

  end
```

but It doesn't work.

So, how to access unicode url on local?

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. We need the minimal code in the question that reproduces the problem. Without that you're asking us to make wild guesses, which is off-topic. Also, grammar is important on SO, so correct spelling and capitalization are significant. Your question is part of an online reference for programming Q&A, not a message board or forum.

Comment: A 404 means the server can't find the URL or doesn't want to display it for some reason. That generally means the URL is wrong.

Comment: url is correct. but it seems to jekyll engine can't read unicode url

Comment: @theTinMan Thank you. Reflected your point.

Comment: I cannot reproduce you 404.
A public repository url can help for debug.

Comment: @DavidJacquel yup, you can access: http://211.197.103.110:4000/
and click any post,
like http://211.197.103.110:4000/%EB%AC%B8%EC%A0%9C%ED%92%80%EC%9D%B4/boj1065/

Comment: I need to seed your code to try to reproduce the error. Maybe you can add me as a temporary collaborator on your private github repository (djacquel).

Comment: @DavidJacquel I have invited you [click the link](https://github.com/NeoMindStd/NeoMindStd.github.io/invitations)

Comment: This really seems to be OS related. I've tested your repository on Ubuntu 18.04 - ruby 2.6.3, and everything works fine.

Comment: @DavidJacquel thx. I will use linux on vm